# How to verify user response using reCaptcha V3 on a custom HTML form in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, recaptcha-v3

I am working a site and the client wanted to add some Eloqua HTML forms into the site. I want to add reCaptcha to these forms as the client was concerned about spam. I have looked at the v3 google documentation and looked at countless guides and videos and I am still stumped.

I am still relatively new to custom PHP for Wordpress implementations, so I am learning as I go.

So far I have managed to hook the form up to a JS function, which then does an AJAX request on the server with the token. The AJAX request runs a function on the server which calls the reCaptcha API. I have verified the token and if its a human, it returns true. If true, the function on the client side submits the form.

I thought this was correct, but I am having doubts as I believe the submission should be done on the server side rather than back on the client side.  But the form action is an Eloqua function e.g. https://s########.t.eloqua.com/e/f2 and all the guides I have seen seem to just send an email.

The reCaptcha seems to work, but I have a feeling the form still may get spammed.

Also I have looked at plugins but all the ones I looked at seemed to be implementations for CF7, not for use on custom HTML forms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The reason for using a CAPTCHA is that we can't trust the client - so still making the client submit the form, would totally defeat the purpose. Sending the data from the server side, would require that they provide you with some sort of API for that - then you can validate that the form submission to your system was genuine via the captcha, and they can validate your request to the API was genuine, by validating your API credentials.

Comment: Other than that, it would only work, if Eloqua themselves validated the captcha. That would usually mean that either they provide you with captcha key and secret to use on your site from their end, or the other way around, you tell the service with secret they can use to validate it. But both those ways would require that they offer any such option in the first place.

Comment: And, if you validated the form submission on your end, and then send it via some API - then that would still not prevent anyone from sending a request to Eloqua _directly_ from elsewhere, mimicking the parameters your form would send. Preventing that would need additional measures.

Comment: In the Eloqua docs for embedding the form into a HTML web page, they literally just dump the form into a web page, with no mention of protecting against spam. https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-user/Help/Forms/Tasks/EmbeddingFormInWebPage.htm

Comment: Not on that particular page maybe, but on the same submenu level you are on there, ten positions further up, there are links to `Form spam protection overview` and `Enabling spam protection for forms` ... (Also says _"Important: This feature is currently released under our Controlled Availability program. To request access to this feature, please contact your account representative for more information."_ on those pages then, but at least the topic seems to be on their radar to a certain extend already.)